# Immutable.js mergeDeepWith issue

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I amusing Immutable.js and having problems merging an object with an array .

My fucntion for merging is:

```
function singleTrackReducer(state = Immutable.Map(singleTrack), action) {
  switch (action.type){
    case AudioFormActions.CHANGE:
        return state.mergeDeepWith((prev, next) => next, action.entity);
    default:
      return state;
    }
}
```

The object that I am merging to looks like this:

```
const singleTrack = {
  songTitle: '',
  mainArtists: [],
  featuredArtists: [],
  releaseDate: '',
  primaryGenre: '',
  isExplicit: false,
  labelName:'',
  upCode: '',
  eanCode: '',
  isrcCode:'',
  copyRight: ''
};
```

I am trying to update the mainArtists property.. For example i can add several artists to my artist array and perform an update successfully. However when I delete an object from the array it appears to be filled with a previous object.

Say for example the artist Array is [drake, rihanna, tyga]

If  I call the function with action entity  [drake, rihanna, tyga, john] it updates fine and the mainArtists property becomes [drake, rihanna, tyga, john].

when I delete an artist example tyga and the array is [drake, rihanna, john]

the mainArtist property becomes [drake, rihanna, john, john]

Can anyone explain how I can resolve this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this code will help you understand the issue:

```
var Immutable = require('immutable');

console.log(
  Immutable.List(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    .mergeDeep(['a', 'c'])
);
// output: List [ "a", "c", "c" ]

console.log(Immutable.List(['a', 'b', 'c'])
  .mergeDeepWith((prev, next) => {
    console.log(`Conflict between ${prev} and ${next}.`);
    return next;
  }, ['a', 'c'])
);
// output: Conflict between a and a.
//         Conflict between b and c.
//         List [ "a", "c", "c" ]
```

Basically, when merging lists, items appear to be copied from one to the other at each index, and if there's already a value at that index, it's considered a conflict:

- For index #0, there's "a" in the first list and "a" in the second list. We resolve the conflict by preferring the second value (though in this case they're identical). So index #0 gets "a".
- Then we go to index #1 and find the first list has "b" and the second list has "c". We resolve the conflict by choosing the second value, so index #1 gets "c".
- Now for index #2, we have no conflict, since only the first list has a value. We keep "c" in index #2, so the final list is "a", "c", "c".

You could instead use a set, but that basically performs a union operation, so nothing would ever be deleted:

```
console.log(
    Immutable.Set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        .mergeDeep(['a', 'c'])
);
// output: Set { "a", "b", "c" }
```

I don't actually think you're looking to do a merge of this list at all... I think you simply want to copy the new value over the old value. If that's the case, maybe you're just looking for `merge` instead of `mergeDeep`:

```
var state = Immutable.Map({
  songTitle: '',
  mainArtists: [],
  featuredArtists: [],
  releaseDate: '',
  primaryGenre: '',
  isExplicit: false,
  labelName:'',
  upCode: '',
  eanCode: '',
  isrcCode:'',
  copyRight: ''
});

function doMerge(state, newState) {
  // no deep merge here, just copy whatever fields are present in newState
  return state.merge(newState);
}

console.log(state.get('mainArtists'));
// output: []

state = doMerge(state, {
  mainArtists: ['drake', 'rihanna', 'tyga']
});
console.log(state.get('mainArtists'));
// output: List [ "drake", "rihanna", "tyga" ]

state = doMerge(state, {
  mainArtists: ['drake', 'rihanna', 'tyga', 'john']
});
console.log(state.get('mainArtists'));
// output: List [ "drake", "rihanna", "tyga", "john" ]

state = doMerge(state, {
    mainArtists: ['drake', 'rihanna', 'john']
});
console.log(state.get('mainArtists'));
// output: List [ "drake", "rihanna", "john" ]
```